# Point Cloud Library - How to assign a single RGB value to an entire point cloud?

Tags: c++, c++11, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I would like to assign a single RGB value to all of the points in a point cloud dataset of type:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>
```

I'm guessing you could iterate through the points and change each value? Using something like this:

```
uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(r) << 16 |
  static_cast<uint32_t>(g) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(b));
point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
```

However, considering I would like to give all points the same value is there a better approach?

The RGB value needs to be associated with each point or at least the collection of points so more than one point cloud can be combined in one output; each with their own distinct colour.

As there are multiple point clouds I am unable to set the colour  through [PCLVisualizer](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php) using:

```
pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ>
```

One idea I had was to just make a high level association with the point cloud:

```
std::tie(rgb, pointcloud) = std::make_tuple(
                                uint32_t, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

Then maybe I could use `PointCloudColorHandlerCustom` multiple times to display the different coloured point clouds on the same PCLVisualizer instance? Not sure if this is possible.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like PCL itself is doing a for loop.
Look here: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/46cb8fe5589e88e36d79f9b8b8e5f4ff4fceb5de/visualization/src/point_cloud_handlers.cpp#L63

So I guess it's not really worth the effort.
However, if you use C++11 you can do it in 1 line (with for_each, transform, range-loop).
Something like this (untested):

```
int32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(r) << 16 |
  static_cast<uint32_t>(g) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(b));
std::transform(cloud->points.begin(), cloud->points.end(), cloud->points.begin(), [rgb](pcl::PointXYZRGB p) { p.rgb = rgb; return p;});
```

or even better a simple range loop

```
int32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(r) << 16 |
      static_cast<uint32_t>(g) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(b));
for(auto &p: cloud->points) p.rgb=rgb;
```

Comment: So, I'm probably better off sticking with storing an RGB value alongside the point cloud rather than iterating? Then later I can use the functionality in PCLVisualizer. Like you said, it doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Your approach is a possibility. Alternatively, you can have a one huge point cloud and use something like pcl::PointXYZL where L stands for Label or pcl::PointXYZI with Intensity. Then you can use PointCloudColorHandlerLabelField or PointCloudColorHandlerGenericField. But then you don't really choose the color values in visualization.

Comment: However, even in this case, if you look the code of the PCL they use loops a lot. So you don't really get away from that.

Comment: That's true. I guess there's little difference between your approach and using the library's behaviour.